# Only keep certain characters in a Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe with many special characters (mainly French accents). I need to merge it with another source for which only certain characters were kept (A-Z 0-9 '- *space*) and others dropped, so the text needs to be cleaned the same way for it to work.

I thought regular expressions would be the key so I tried the two options below.

```
df['city'] = re.sub("[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'-. ]", "", df['city'] )    
df['city'] = df['city'] .apply(lambda x: re.sub("[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'-. ]","",x))
```

The first option gives me TypeError: expected string or buffer while the 2nd give TypeError: expected string or buffer.

When I test on just one string the code works, so I have a feeling it's a little glitch somewhere. I can't put my hand on it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['city'].str.replace("[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'-. ]", "")
```

is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Awesome even simpler!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the 2nd example will work. Maybe there is None in the `city` column? Please try as follows.

```
REGEX_STR = "[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'-. ]"
df['city'] = df['city'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("", x) if x else '')
```